# In terraform, how to assign variable in a resource block only if condition matches

Tags: if-statement, terraform, teleport

I am trying to set a variable in a block only if a condition matches.

```
resource "teleport_role" "test_role" {
  spec = {
    allow = {
      kubernetes_labels = {
        "label_1" = "${local.some_var == "something" ? ["value_1"] : null}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When a `false` condition, in `terrform plan` I get:

```
+ "label_1" = null
```

which eventually throws error during `terraform apply`:

```bash
│ When applying changes to teleport_role. test_role, provider
│ "provider[\"terraform.releases.teleport.dev/gravitational/teleport\"]"
│ produced an unexpected new value:
│ .spec.allow.kubernetes_labels["label_1"]: was null, but now
│ cty.ListVal([]cty.Value{cty.StringVal("")}).
```

In nutshell, `null` doesn't let `label_1` be ignored.

How do I ensure that variable just don't get assigned at all if condition is `false`

For example if I had to do it in Python, it would have been like:

```py
if some_var == "something":
   label_1 = value_1
```

Ref: https://github.com/gravitational/teleport-plugins/issues/657

Answer (score 1):

This is erroring because Kubernetes does not allow this kind of specification in its spec schema for that API. `go-cty` does seem to be trying really hard to coerce that HCL2/TF type into something compatible with Kubernetes spec schema, so good on them for that effort.

In most languages (this one included) with potentially unspecified values for enumerables/iterables, then the unspecified needs to be empty instead of nil/null/etc.

```
kubernetes_labels = local.some_var == "something" ? { "label_1" = ["value_1"] } : {}
```

There is a very small chance that `go` will be unable to serialize that for the Kubernetes manifest (in which case the conditional needs to be at a higher key), but this is code for how to achieve this specifically and generally in Terraform.